# Облачная база данных

Tags: база-данных

Есть учебный центр в котором возникла необходимость клиентской базы данных. Так как центра три необходима синхронизация. Необходимо создать базу данных на сервере с доступом через сайт. Есть какие то системы для этого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наилучшим решением проблемы стал adminer